# Add user home directory depending hostname

Tags: hostname, users, home-directory

Is it possible to add a list of users and change the home directory of each user depending on the host name of the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. That's pretty vague, could you edit your question to add some examples and some information about the environment you are using?

Comment: You don't even say what OS you're using.